# Django: advanced query

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have `Session` that is composed of `Phrase` and each `Phrase` is composed of `Mot` in a special order through the field `ordre`, like that:

```
class Phrase(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Mot(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Session(BaseModel):
    pass

class SessionPhrase(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session)
    phrase = models.ForeignKey(Phrase)

class SessionPhraseMot(models.Model):
    session_phrase = models.ForeignKey(SessionPhrase)
    mot = models.ForeignKey(Mot)
    ordre = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
```

I have a `Session` generic detail view where I want to show all the `Mot` of the `Phrase` of the current session throught `self.object`.

I tried to begin with something like:

```
sp = SessionPhrase.objects.filter(session=self.object)
```

But now I'm stuck... any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found it but I don't know if it's the cleanest & proper way to do it:

```
sps = SessionPhrase.objects.filter(session=self.object)
result = [SessionPhraseMot.objects
          .filter(session_phrase=sp)
          .order_by('ordre') for sp in sps]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution causes additional database queries for every `SessionPhrase` object which can lead to bad performance depending on how big your database is.

By [spanning relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) only one query is needed:

```
session_phrase_mots = SessionPhraseMot.objects.filter(session_phrase__session=self.object).order_by('ordre')
```

---

You generally start with the type of object you want to have (in this case it's `SessionPhraseMot`). For example if you want all `Mot` objects related to the current session you would do it this way:

```
mots = Mot.objects.filter(sessionphrasemot_set__session_phrase__session=self.object)
```

Also have a look at [Following relationships “backward”](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).